# Ordering columns according to columns values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

SO I have the below

```
Name Tues Mon Tues Mon 
col   0    0   1    1       <-
bill  2    1   2    1
jon   4    3   4    3
```

and i want to order the dataframe columns according to the "col" row to group 0's and 1's
in order but also in order according the days of the week so below is the result.

```
Name Mon Tues Mon Tues 
col   0    0   1    1
bill  1    2   1    2
jon   3    4   3    4
```

Comment: @Marshalmc please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. It's easier to sort by rows, so you can use `.T` to transpose the dataframe and then use `.T` to transpose it back after running some operations.
2. The first thing it looks like you need to do is sort by the day of the week? You can crate a new column that replaces the partial Weekday strings to numbers, so you can sort in order by day of week, and then drop that column after sorting.

---

```
df = df.set_index('Name').T.reset_index()
df['day'] = df['index'].replace(['Su.*', 'M.*', 'Tu.*', 'W.*', 'Th.*', 'F.*', 'Sa.*'],
                                [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], regex=True)
df = df.sort_values(['col', 'day']).drop('day', axis=1).set_index('index').T.reset_index()
df
Out[1]: 
index  Name  Mon  Tues  Mon.1  Tues.1
0       col    0     0      1       1
1      bill    1     2      1       2
2       jon    3     4      3       4
```

You can chnage the column names with:

```
df.columns = [col.split('.')[0] for col in df.columns]

    Name    Mon Tues Mon Tues
0   col       0    0    1   1
1   bill      1    2    1   2
2   jon       3    4    3   4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `df` by the following simple self-explained line

```
df_sorted = df.T.sort_values(['col', 'bill']).T
```